# Searching array list by partial user entry JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to search and print an ArrayList value by user entry with a JAVA program.

The user will enter an ID (string) and I would like to print the ArrayList entry or entries containing the ID entered. All ID's in the ArrayList are all in all caps, hence the .toUpperCase() I use in the code below.

I currently have made the ArrayList searchable by only a complete match of ID's. For example if an ID is "HOUSE" the user can only enter the full ID "house" to get the ArrayList value returned.

I would like to add the feature of partial entry to return a value(s) in the array list. For example if two ID's are "HOUSE" and "HOUSTON", I would like the user to be able to enter "hou" and get both arraylist values returned that contain "hou."

I am new to JAVA and I have researched on here quite a bit but am still can't get a partial entry on here to work. I would appreciate any help. Here is the code I put together for the complete ID entry.

```
public void find(ArrayList<Plants> pl) {

    boolean found = false;
    int i = 0;
    String inputName = null;

    System.out.println("Enter the ID or partial ID of the plant you would like to find: ");
    inputName = input.nextLine();

    String nameCaps = inputName.toUpperCase();

    while(!found && i < pl.size()) {

        String id = pl.get(i).getId();

        if (id.equals(nameCaps)) {
            found = true;
            System.out.println(pl.get(i).toString());
        }
        else {
            i ++;
        }
    }

    if (!found) {
        System.out.println("A plant with that ID does not exist");
    }

} // find end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`startsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-) method from String class.
So, you can do like (not breaking the loop after finding one entry as you want to print all possible matches)

```
for (int i = 0; i < pl.size(); i++) {
    String id = pl.get(i).getId();

    if (id.startsWith(nameCaps)) {
        found = true;
        System.out.println(pl.get(i).toString());
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the comments by Aominè@, you can just use a for-each loop here

```
for (Plant plant : pl) {
   if (plant.getId().startsWith(nameCaps)) {
   ...
  }
}
```

Comment: you could use an enhanced for loop. don't see why we need a for loop here as you're only using the index to access the elements in the list.

Comment: @Aominè Yes. But I wanted to keep it as close to what the OP has tried so far. You can even solve this using Java 8 streams.

Comment: fair enough... I typically use a for loop when I need to have access to the elements and do something with the index at the same time, if I am only interested in the elements then I usually go for the enhanced for loop. but that's a matter of preference i guess.

Comment: yes, this worked great! Much simpler as well, even when you do end up typing in an entire ID. I was not familiar with the startswith method from the string class. I would upvote your answer, but I don't have 15 rep :(

Comment: You are welcome.. You can still accept the answer if it solved your problem